# Annoying "Resource not found" warnings on my web.xml with Eclipse Indigo

Tags: web.xml, eclipse-indigo, custom-error-pages, prettyfaces

I have two custom url mappings for error pages (500 and 404) using PrettyFaces. On my web.xml I have these two error page rules:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/not-found</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

The problem is that Eclipse insists in warn me that the `/error` and `/not-found` resources cannot be found in my webapp path.

How can I get rid of these annoying warnings? I don't want to lose the web.xml validation though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have any file in web.xml that has an invalid mapping. I'm guessing you are probably using JBoss Tools? If so, if you go into the Eclipse Preferences, type Validation into the filter, find the JBoss Tools validations, and turn off the web.xml validations. That should do the trick.

Preferences -> JBoss Tools -> Web -> Vefication -> (then disable all the rules you don't want.)

Comment: I'm indeed using JBoss Tools for Indigo, but I couldn't find these options :( I'm using JBoss Tools development milestone 3.3.0.M4.

Comment: That's the same version I am using. Try pressing CTRL-3, or COMMAND-3 on mac to bring up the quick-menu. Then type: verification.

Comment: You should see the only option there will take you to the menu I am talking about.

Comment: Found it! Awesome! Thanks! And congratulations for the great work on Pretty Faces! :)